# FFMpeg How to convert a growing image sequence to video

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I have a small app that writes images to a folder, with sequential file names, for example:

```
00001.png
00002.png
00003.png
...
02030.png
02031.png
```

And I want to use FFMpeg (or anything similar) to convert the image sequence to a video file.

Using this command I am able to create the video file, once the script has finished writing all the files:

```
ffmpeg -i %05d.png out.avi
```

But I am looking for a way to create the video file, **while** the image sequence is still being written

Is this possible? any suggestions would be really appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 0):

Make a script that sends the images as an **MJPEG** stream as they arrive in your folder. Use the resulting stream as input for your `ffmpeg` command.

Example server in node.js:
https://github.com/psanford/node-mjpeg-test-server